# How to get a rolling latest tag in the docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to understand the docker registry and it's tagging.

I'm actually using the gitlab registry.

Scenario:

I push `image1:latest`

Five minutes later I push `image1:latest` again.

I only have one instance of `image1:latest` in my registry.

I'm guessing that a tag is just text with no semantic meaning which is understood. So the registry cannot keep only one image with the `latest` tag. It'd doesn't understand that `latest` means something.

What I need, if I am understanding this correctly, is a way to only have one image with the `latest` tag. So in my example above, I would see..

`image1 - Uploaded 5 minutes ago`

`image1:latest - Uploaded 30 seconds ago`

If it doesn't work this way then what is the correct versioning strategy for containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article on medium will help clear up a lot of confusion.

https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375

In my case, we typically version the number of our image builds, for example, tagging the image with image1:v_1, will create an image image1:v_1. What also happens is that image1:v_1 can also be referenced using image1:latest. So if you keep tagging image1 with image1:latest it doesn't really have a tag, it just knows that it's the latest. Hope that wasn't too confusing.

Comment: Very helpful thanks. The problem I have now is how to get a version number into the .gitlab-ci.yml file. I don't want to have to update the build definition each time I change version. How are you handling this?

Comment: Since everything is automated through the Jenkins/Shell scripting, I basically have a template yml, and use `sed` to replace the version number each time with a build number. But in your case, if you don't care at all about the tags, just push it without a tag and use `:latest` every time you want to use the image in a container.

Comment: Good answer but in my case I'll need to find out which version is last published. In my script I need to resolve and run it. Now, is there any cli command for getting latest push?

Comment: Please write the solution here as the link might gets removed